# Passing View to OnCreateViewHolder() in RecyclerViewAdapter is not working as expected

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm a beginner to android. I'm trying to implement a `RecyclerView`. I created a view in my activity and then I passed the view to the adapter constructor like below.

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LinearLayout lv = new LinearLayout(this);
    lv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    View v = new TextView(this);
    v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    v.setId(R.id.reservedId);
    lv.addView(v);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    // Passing the created view to the adapter.
    AdapterRecylerView mAdapter = new AdapterRecylerView(this, lv);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

In the adapter i created a public view and assigned the passed view to that one and accessing the view in the `onCreateViewHolder` like below.

```
private class AdapterRecylerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRecylerView.ViewHolder>{
    private Context context;
    private View lv;

    public AdapterRecylerView(Context context, LinearLayout lv) {
        this.context = context;
        this.lv = lv;
    }

    @Override
    public AdapterRecylerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Using the passed view
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(lv);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AdapterRecylerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(""+(position+1));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 100;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView mTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.reservedId);
        }
    }
}
```

When i run the code i cant able to see the views. Looks like the view is occupying the entire parent. The first text is shown in the top left corner and the last text is shown in the bottom left corner like below. When i scroll can't able some of the views.

[image: First text shown in the top left corner]
[image: Last text shown in the bottom left corner]

I don't know what is the issue. Am I doing anything wrong. Anybody please help me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems form using a single View instance/object for all of your `ViewHolder`s. You need to create a separate instance of your View for each `ViewHolder` instance.